# Luxon setZone not working when getting epoch time (valueOf)

Tags: datetime, luxon

I have been trying to use [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/) to get (for comparison reasons) the epoch miliseconds from two DateTimes in different timezone.

I'm using the [.valueOf()](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimevalueof) method to do so, but even that I'm setting the different timezones for each DateTime, that method always return the same value:

```
const { DateTime } = require('luxon')

const dtString = '2022-01-15 13:00:00'

const d1 = DateTime.fromSQL(dtString).setZone('America/Sao_Paulo').valueOf()
const d2 = DateTime.fromSQL(dtString).setZone('America/New_York').valueOf()

console.log(d1) // logs 1642262400000
console.log(d2) // logs 1642262400000 (same)
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of parsing the dates in one zone and then shifting the times around, just parse them in the zone you want:

```js
const dtString = '2022-01-15 13:00:00';
const d1 = DateTime.fromSQL(dtString, { zone: "America/Sao_Paulo" }).valueOf();
const d2 = DateTime.fromSQL(dtString, { zone: "America/New_York" }).valueOf();

d1 //=> 1642262400000
d2 //=> 1642269600000
```

The difference there is that in yours, Luxon parses the string using your system zone. Then you change the zone, but the time is still the time, unless you use `keepLocalTime`. In mine, I'm telling Luxon what zone to use in *interpreting* the string, which results in a different time being computed for the two cases.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this Luxon issue](https://github.com/moment/luxon/issues/143), I found the fix for that:

We should use the `keepCalendarTime: true` option in the `setZone` method to make it work.

> That extra flag says "yes, change the actual time"

So the functional code looks like:

```
const { DateTime } = require('luxon')

const dtString = '2022-01-15 13:00:00'
const opts = { keepCalendarTime: true }

const d1 = DateTime.fromSQL(dtString).setZone('America/Sao_Paulo', opts).valueOf()
const d2 = DateTime.fromSQL(dtString).setZone('America/New_York', opts).valueOf()

console.log(d1) // logs 1642262400000
console.log(d2) // logs 1642269600000 (prints different value)
```